# Zod schema for a string starting with a letter

Tags: typescript, zod

I have this type in typescript, that the string must start with `A` letter.

```
type StringStartsWithA = `A${string}`
```

When I want to create a zod schema, thats what I use:

```
const StringStartsWithASchema = z.string().startsWith("A")
```

But then the inferred type is just a normal string.

```
type StringStartsWithA = z.infer<typeof Schema> // string
```

Is there a way to solve this, so the inferred type also requires to start with the `A` letter? So it will match the original typescript type?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#custom-schemas)

> You can create a Zod schema for any TypeScript type by using
> z.custom(). This is useful for creating schemas for types that are not
> supported by Zod out of the box, such as template string literals.
>
> ```js
> const px = z.custom<`${number}px`>((val) => /^\d+px$/.test(val));
> px.parse("100px"); // pass
> px.parse("100vw"); // fail
> ```

So, for your situation:

```js
const StringStartsWithA = z.custom<`A${string}`>((val: any) => /^A/.test(val));
type StringStartsWithA = z.infer<typeof StringStartsWithA> // type StringStartsWithA = `A${string}`
```